# How to check if user has admin id to access page?

Tags: php, discord

How to check if user has the $AdminID to access page?
$_SESSION['iroles'] is my discord roles

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
} else {
    header("location: login.php");
}

for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($_SESSION['iroles']); $x++) {
    $CheckID = $_SESSION['iroles'][$x];
    if ($CheckID == $AdminID) {
        $AdminID = "10084505484727420002";
        $Access = true;
    } else {
        header("Location: error.php");
        $Access = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Any errors? Assign the variable _before_ you check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//User Role
$AdminID = "10084505484727420002";

//Roles stored in an array
$iroles =  $_SESSION['iroles'];

//Checking for user access using in_array function

if (in_array($AdminID, $iroles)){
    //Match found
    $Access = true;
}else {
    header("Location: error.php");
    $Access = false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `$Access = false;` ? `exit` after your `header` call makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The access variable should be ommited and be replaced by exit;